# Как убрать полосу в заголовке приложения?

Tags: android, design

Вопрос от новичка программирования Android.

Есть свежесгенерированный, мною ещё не изменённый проект. Несмотря на почти пустое содержание activity_main.xml, в приложении отображается вот-эта полоса:

[image]

Как её убрать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вставь в теге <activity>, в которой хочешь убрать title код:
android:theme="[@android](/users/8445/android):style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"

Comment: во точно =) а я поленился поискать правильный тег =)

Answer (score 12):

```
// Убрать ActionBar
getSupportActionBar().hide();

// Показать ActionBar
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Answer (score 7):

Добавь в onCreate

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 4):

\res\values\styles.xml

Выбираем тему без экшн бара:

```html
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

и еще строчку можно добавить:

```html
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

В стилях (styles.xml) parent поменять на "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" или поставить "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 0):

android:style="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"

как то так в манифесте

или на экране настройки активити, сверху есть темы, так ее можно поменять.. на напи ниже 13 ее не будет..

Comment: В манифесте куда не впихнуть, везде ошибка. 

Такой бар вроде-бы на всех темах.

И мне надо так-же поддерживать юзеров, api которых 14+

Answer (score 0):

замени:
сlass MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

на:
class MainActivity extends Activity

полоса уйдёт.
и не надо там столько xmlлить ..

Answer (score 0):

попробуй вот этот код :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // задать fullscreen

this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // задать No Title

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    }

}
```

*AHTUNG !!!111 : у меня скомпилилось, но при открытии приложение крашиться.

**Теперь же с НИЖЕследующим кодом все работет :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else {
     /* скрыть строку состояния status bar, но будет виден action bar :
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); */
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
     // скрыть и status bar и action bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

AHTUNG v.2.0 !!!111
при выходе и входе заново в приложение(кнопка хоум и т.д.),  галиматья вверху экрана снова появится. Потому, как я думаю, нужно продублировать код в методах onResume(){} и/или onRestart(){}.

Answer (score 0):

В старых версиях место style.xml присутствует 2 файла themes.xml
Один для обычного вида, а другой для ночного режима
Для дневного режима:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">` 
Ночной режим следует тоже изменить таким же образом.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к вышеприведенным решениям, если вы генерировали проект из шаблона BottomNavigationActivity (и, возможно, из некоторых других) в AndroidStudio, попробуйте удалить в `activity_main.xml` следующую строку:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Это уберет отступ сверху, который обычно занимает заголовок

Answer (score -1):

> Вставь в теге , в которой хочешь убрать title код:
>   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"

У меня не заработала.

> android:style="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"
>
> как то так в манифесте

тоже не заработала.

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Совет привел к Runtime Exception.

> getSupportActionBar().hide();

Единственный вариант, который заработал.

Хотелось бы разделить код и разметку, но по-другому не получилось.